# How does an operator in the denominator act on a state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

I am reading The Quantum Theory of light by Rodney Loudon.

In Chapter 7 the author defines a phase operator $\hat{\phi}$ using the destruction $\hat{a}$ and creation $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ operators of the quantum-harmonic oscillator as follows.

$\hat{a} = (\hat{n}+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}exp(i\hat{\phi})$ and $\hat{a}^{\dagger} = exp(-i\hat{\phi})(\hat{n}+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ leading to
$exp(i\hat{\phi}) = (\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\hat{a}$ and $exp(-i\hat{\phi})= \hat{a}^{\dagger} (\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ where $\hat{n} = \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}$.

How would one apply the operator $exp(i\hat{\phi})$ to the states $\vert n \rangle$? Here is my attempt [based on the book]:

$$
exp(i\hat{\phi}) \vert n \rangle = (\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\hat{a} \vert n \rangle = (\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} n^{\frac{1}{2}} \vert n-1 \rangle =  n^{\frac{1}{2}} (\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}  \vert n-1 \rangle
$$

At this point I get stuck. How does the operator $\hat{n}$ act on the state $\vert n \rangle$ when it is under a square root and also in the denominator?

Edit:

So based on the answer and comment below we have $(\hat{n}+1)\vert n-1 \rangle = (n-1+1)\vert n-1 \rangle = n \vert n-1 \rangle$.

Now $f(\hat{n}+1) = (\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ therefore $(\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}  \vert n-1 \rangle = n^{-\frac{1}{2}} \vert n-1 \rangle$.

This results in

$$
exp(i\hat{\phi}) \vert n \rangle = (\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\hat{a} \vert n \rangle = (\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} n^{\frac{1}{2}} \vert n-1 \rangle =  n^{\frac{1}{2}} (\hat{n}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}  \vert n-1 \rangle = \\ n^{\frac{1}{2}} n^{-\frac{1}{2}} \vert n-1 \rangle = \vert n-1 \rangle
$$

Comment: If $Av=\lambda v$, then $f(A)v=f(\lambda)v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by Filippo tells you everything you need to know, but I will explain a little.

When we write a quantity such as $\exp(i \hat{\phi})$ we are giving ourselves the 'right' to evaluate a function such as $\exp$ on an operator-valued quantity. How can we do that? Is it even well-defined? The answer is that prior to writing $\exp(i \hat{\phi})$ we first *define* what we mean by it. In this case a suitable definition is
$$
\exp(i \hat{\phi}) := 1 + i \hat{\phi} + (i\hat{\phi})^2/2 + (i\hat{\phi})^3 / 3! + \cdots
$$
using the Taylor series expansion and this is the standard definition.

Another way to proceed is to define a function of an operator by asserting how it behaves when acting on a complete set of states, and for a Hermitian operator a suitable complete set is the set of eigenstates. One typically asserts
$$
f(\hat{\phi}) | u_\lambda \rangle = f(\lambda) | u_\lambda \rangle
$$
where $| u_\lambda \rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat\phi$:
$$
\hat{\phi} | u_\lambda \rangle = \lambda| u_\lambda \rangle.
$$

In your book the author is clearly doing one or both of the above for general functions of operators.